# Preventing cursor from jumping to org-agenda buffer when marking as DONE from org-agenda

Tags: org-agenda

Problem: I am on my org-agenda buffer, and mark a task as DONE (t d). Next, I find myself in the org buffer of that particular task, but I want to prevent the jumping to the that buffer of the task. I want to remain in the org-agenda buffer, which now should show me the task as DONE, but still remaining in the org-agenda buffer. Is there a customizable variable for this?